# VSTO Word Content Control - adding multiple RichTextContentControls at run time

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in, word-addins

I'm creating a Word add-in which allows the user to select various text in a Word document and click a button on the ribbon which will wrap that text with a Content Control (rich text). Eventually these content controls will then be mapped to XML.

The code so far is like this:

```
public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private RichTextContentControl titleRichTextControl;

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void addTitle_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            AddRichTextControlAtSelection();
        }


        private void AddRichTextControlAtSelection()
        {
            word.Document currentDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

           currentDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Select();

           Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(currentDocument);

            titleRichTextControl = extendedDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl("titleRichTextControl");
            titleRichTextControl.PlaceholderText = "Enter the title";
            titleRichTextControl.Title = "Title";
            titleRichTextControl.Tag = "title";

        }

    }
```

All this is fine and it works for the first time the button is clicked. However, if there is more than one 'title' (in this case) that needs adding, and the user presses the button a second time, it throws the error:

```
The control cannot be added because a control with the name titleRichTextControl already exists in the Controls collection.
```

It's clear why it complains, but i can't think of the correct way to go to allow multiple clicks of the button to generate multiple content controls of the same type (rich text content control) and the same name ("title" for example).

Can anybody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: "i can't think of the correct way" - well, perhaps start with "a way", e.g. iterate through the controls, pick up existing titles, and think of a way to avoid duplicating an existing title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was how i did it in the end:

```
private void addTitle_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            AddRichTextControlAtSelection();
        }


        int count = 0;
        private void AddRichTextControlAtSelection()
        {
            word.Document currentDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;

            Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(currentDocument);

            if (currentDocument.ContentControls.Count > 0)
            {

                currentDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = word.WdColorIndex.wdYellow;
                currentDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Select();

                richTextControls = new List<RichTextContentControl>(); 

                foreach (word.ContentControl nativeControl in currentDocument.ContentControls)
                {
                    if (nativeControl.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText) 
                    {
                        count++;
                        RichTextContentControl tempControl = extendedDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl("VSTORichTextControl" + count.ToString());
                        richTextControls.Add(tempControl);
                        tempControl.Title = "Title";
                        tempControl.Tag = "title";

                        break;
                     }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                RichTextContentControl VSTORichTextControl;
                VSTORichTextControl = extendedDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl("VSTORichTextControl");
                VSTORichTextControl.PlaceholderText = "Enter the DM title";
                VSTORichTextControl.Title = "Title";
                VSTORichTextControl.Tag = "title";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes, this is "standard" - some kind of collection and incrementing name. If you don't need the VSTO extensions for content controls you could insert them at the "interop" level, then you wouldn't run into this problem. The "Name" is only for VSTO - Word itself doesn't need it.